# Pandas - AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: python, pandas

I have this error and I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my code  :

```
time_start = data_h_df['hour']
frequency = data_h_df['FREQUENCY']
timezone = data_h_df['TIMEZONE']
outputMode = OutputMode('EEA',time_start, frequency, pytz.timezone(timezone),CONST_MODE_CONT,IDCase1())
```

When I don't use variables but I put the values directly in parameters like this, I don't have an error :

```
outputMode = OutputMode('EEA','06:00:00','08:00:00',pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'),CONST_MODE_CONT,IDCase1())
```

I don't know if it can help, these columns have this form in the dataframe :

```
hour         FREQUENCY      TIMEZONE
06:00:00     08:00:00       Europe/Paris
```

Comment: Are you trying to make TIMEZONE in upper case?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, no I have not tried the problem is there ?

Comment: We don't know what `OutputMode` is, is it contained inside `pytz`'? Please include the missing import statements and retest your code executes without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
time_start = data_h_df['hour'][0]
frequency = data_h_df['FREQUENCY'][0]
timezone = data_h_df['TIMEZONE'][0]
```

It's a type error from the Data frame: you're accessing the column, which is returned as a Pandas Series. With the [0] you get the actual element within the Series.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and I don't have the error anymore !

Answer (score 1):

Your are extracting columns from your dataframe here. These columns are of type Series and your are passing those Series objects to OutputMode. Probably, you just want to get the first entry of each column/series, which you get by

```py
time_start = data_h_df['hour'][0]
frequency = data_h_df['FREQUENCY'][0]
timezone = data_h_df['TIMEZONE'][0]
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and I don't have the error anymore. Someone before you also told me this solution I have already accepted his solution but thank you !